# MySQL 5.0 reporting "concat does not exist"

Tags: mysql, sql, function, select, concatenation

I have a query with a complex concatenation in it. It's something along the lines of concatenating the results of several sub-selects if the results are not null. It works fine (though the complexity makes me a little sick) on our development server which runs MySQL 5.1 but our production server, which runs 5.0 reports

```
FUNCTION database.concat does not exist
```

Any ideas why this might be? Upgrading is unfortunately not an option at this point so unless someone has a bright idea I'm pretty much stuck rewriting this report.

Query is as follows (Yes I realize I'm horribly abusing mysql. Let's set that aside for now. If anyone knows how of a way to refer to a subselect by alias that would be handy, but I've never been able to do it, hence the repeated subselect. Also concat returns `NULL` if any of  the arguments are `NULL`, hence the if statements.)

```sql
select (concat(if((select 
                       concat(if(b.foo is not null, b.foo, ""), 
                       " ", 
                       if(f.bar is not null, f.bar, ""))
                     from  `foo_table`  as f
                      left join `bar_table` as b
                        on b.SOME_ID = f.SOME_ID
                     where f.STUDENT_ID = t.STUDENT_ID
                       and bar.NewID = t.OldID order by bar.id limit 1) is not null,
                   (select 
                      concat(if(b.foo is not null, b.foo, ""), 
                       " ", 
                       if(f.bar is not null, f.bar, ""))
                     from  `foo_table`  as f
                      left join `bar_table` as b
                        on b.SOME_ID = f.SOME_ID
                     where f.STUDENT_ID = t.STUDENT_ID
                       and bar.NewID = t.OldID order by bar.id limit 1),
                   ""),
       " ",
       t.reason) as Reason
   from table as t
```

Comment: We can't spot typos, etc without a snippet. Concat should be there and take only two arguments.

Comment: @Matt William concat can take an arbitrary number arguments according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: Could you please post the query and exact error message?

Comment: @docgnome, yep you are right. My mistake. Quassinoi caught me too

Comment: This really won't help unless you post the whole query.

Comment: Actually... I just read the whole entry from concat_ws and I think using that will greatly simplify this query...

Comment: This is an awful use of correlated subqueries by the way.

Comment: @Mchl Yes, yes it is. See my answer for a much cleaner version.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

And make sure, that there is no whitespace between `concat` and `(`. Something like that:

```
SELECT CONCAT ('a', 'b');
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Not the problem though.

Comment: As i told you, there is space between concat and `(`. MySQL 5.0 had such problem. In 5.1 it has been solved.

Comment: Typo, sorry. Will post a simplified query in a moment.

Comment: Pretty sure this is what caused the original issue now. But I missed it before on one of them in all the complexity. I rewrote the whole thing and didn't make that mistake again.

Comment: there are times when MySql makes me say WHAT THE FOO!

Answer (score 5):

`CONCAT` is avaiable in `5.0`.

Make sure you didn't make a typo:

```
SELECT  CONTACT(id, name)
FROM    items;

Error Code: 1305
FUNCTION test.CONTACT does not exist
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that was just in my question. The same query runs on our development server under 5.1 but doesn't under 5.0 so I know that it's not a typo issue.

Answer (score 2):

I rewrote the query using `concat_ws` which simply ignores `NULL` values instead of returning `NULL` like `concat` does. Here is the result that is greatly simplified and actually works.

```
select concat_ws(" ", 
                 (select 
                    concat_ws(" ", b.bar, f.foo)
                   from  `foo_table`  as f
                   left join `bar_table` as  b
                     on b.SOME_ID = f.SOME_ID
                  where f.STUDENT_ID = t.STUDENT_ID
                    and f.NewID = t.OldID order by f.id limit 1 ),
               t.reason) as Reason,
   from table as t
```